# looking for the intel RAID driver

Tags: drivers, raid, mdadm, dmraid

I currently using CentOS and I would like to move to Ubuntu. I need help finding a Intel driver for the RAID 1 that I am using (motherboard feature).

```
System Information
Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name: PH67A-UD3-B3
Version:  

$ lspci | egrep -i 'raid|adaptec'
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 05)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find that information with `lspci -v`. In you case, you could list the information of the storage controller only with the command as follows.

```
lspci -s 00:1f.2 -v
```

This contains a line `Kernel driver in use` which lists the kernel driver used for that device.

Comment: "Kernel driver in use: ahci" . OK. Great, where can I find this for Ubuntu?

Comment: The `ahci` driver is shipped with the kernel. No need to install an extra package.

Comment: I understand for CentOS. But if it ships with Ubuntu, then why it is not working?

Comment: You maybe should rephrase your question or ask a new one and describe which problems you actually are experiencing. From your question above, there is not hint that something is not working. "Not working" is a very vague problem description.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The raid 1 is not working and after research it seems that it due to this driver been missing. If it is available then it could be something else.

Comment: The motherboard RAID provided by Intel (on laptops at least) are controlled by a BIOS setting where you switch between `AHCI` and `RAID`. It is called **Fake RAID** by many people: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_with_Fake_RAID